# How to select all multipoint features from a point layer?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

I'm connecting to WFS layer by qgis. On some layer I've got points features and few multi-point features. Whole layer contains about 1000 features, how can I do some query just to know which features is multipoint geometry?

Comment: which version of qgis?

Comment: Do you really have a mix of Point and Multipoint features, or do you have all Multipoint features, and you want to select those that have more than one point within them?

Comment: @smithkm yes, when I was trying to export to shapefile I've got message, that geometry type is mixed, and I need to default one type of geometry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the Geometries into CSV format with a WKT (well known text) field containing the types.  Load the CSV into Spatialite using QGIS's Qspatialite plugin.  Run an SQL SELECT WHERE WKT LIKE  "something%something" to search for the strings that are indicative of the data types you are looking for.

To create a WKT field, export the shapefile (other formats?) by typing
 `GEOMETRY=AS_WKT` 
in the OGR Layer option, of QGIS SAVE AS, then Save As CSV and QGIS.
The WKT field should have the data you build your SQL SELECT statement with.

Comment: thanks, I didnt figure it out before.I saved to geoJSON, and then I've got geometry type by default.